# Странное поведение бесконечного цикла while

Tags: c#

В отдельном потоке запускаю бесконечный цикл. В цикле обрабатываю значения публичного List которые сохраняются в базу данных. В окне программы при каждой интерации выводится номер итерации, `List.Count`, `clientCount`. Все отлично работает но по истечении времени, всегда разного, в окно проги выводится одни и те же значения, кроме номера итерации который инкриментируется при каждом выводе.

Т.е. сам поток не зависает, бесконечный цикл работает но все что в цикле не выполняется. В цикле есть даже задержка на пол секунды. Так вот даже она перестает работать. т.е. до сбоя сообщение выводилось не чаще 2 раза в секунду, после непонятного для меня сбоя сообщениями просто заваливает.

```
public void Circle(Object StateInfo)
{
    try
    {
        newDatas = new List<MarketData>();
        newDepths = new List<MarketDepth>();
        newInst = new List<Instrument>();
        int clienCount = 0;
        int whileCnt = 0;
        int cntSaveToDB = 0;
        int cntZero = 0;


        while (true)
        {
            try {

                Thread.Sleep(500);

                myEvent("While: " + whileCnt + " RequestList: " + requestList.Count + " clientCount: " + clienCount);

                for (int i = 0; ((i < requestList.Count) & (i < 1100)); i++)
                {
                    if (requestList[0] != null)
                    {
                        var arr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(requestList[0], ";");
                        ArrToObj(arr);
                        requestList.RemoveAt(0);
                        clienCount++;
                        //for debuging
                        //myEvent("For: " + i + " RequestList: " + requestList.Count + " clientCount: " + clienCount);
                     }
                }

                if ((clienCount >= quantToSave)||(cntZero > 2))
                {
                    cntSaveToDB++;
                    BaseContext clientContext = new BaseContext(connectionString);
                    clientContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                    clientContext.Instruments.AddRange(newInst);
                    clientContext.MarketDatas.AddRange(newDatas);
                    clientContext.MarketDepths.AddRange(newDepths);

                    myCnt("Сохранено в базу записей: " + clientContext.SaveChanges());
                    myCnt("В очереди на сохранение в базу :" + requestList.Count);

                    newInst.Clear();
                    newDatas.Clear();
                    newDepths.Clear();
                    clienCount = 0;

                    clientContext.Dispose();

                    myCnt("Всего сохранений в бд " + cntSaveToDB);
                    whileCnt = 0;
                    cntZero = 0;
                }

                if((requestList.Count == 0)&(clienCount != 0))
                {
                    cntZero++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cntZero = 0;
                }

                whileCnt++;

            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                myErr(exc.ToString());
                writeError(exc.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {                            
        writeError(exc.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Внимание: какие то проблемы \r\n" + exc.ToString() + "\r\n Необходимо перезапустить сервер");
    }

}
```

Comment: Для работы в разных потоках лучше использовать SynchronizedCollection<T> к примеру - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша основная проблема - в том, что когда `requestList[0]` оказывается `null` - он так и остается навсегда. Просто потому что строчка `requestList.RemoveAt(0);` выполняется только для ненулевых запросов. Ее надо выполнять во всех случаях.

Проблема номер два - небезопасная работа с потоками.

Проблема номер три - активное ожидание. Программа занимает процессор даже если ничего не делает.

Все проблемы можно решить если вместо списка воспользоваться классом [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) поверх [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
BlockingCollection<string> requestsQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>(new ConcurrentQueue<string>());

// ...

while (!requestsQueue.IsCompleted) {
  try {
    var request = requestsQueue.Take(); // Этот метод выполняет ожидание если очередь пуста
    var i = 0;
    do {
      // Обработка запроса request как вы делали ранее
    } while (++i < 1100 && requestsQueue.TryTake(out request)); // Получаем новый запрос если очередь не пуста - но не более 1100 запросов в пакете.

    // Дальше как было
  } catch /*...*/ { /*...*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто определите в какой момент он перестает выходить из Вашего цикла ***for***. И если в нем (и ниже) Вы используете логические выражения, то поменяйте ***&*** на ***&&***.

Comment: && - не помогло, а по поводу вложенного цикла, он как будто в него не попадает

Comment: Вообще-то смысл был в том, что Вы определите, когда и почему у Вас перестают соблюдаться условия выхода из цикла for. А не бездумно поменять одно на другое. Можно же воспользоваться дебагером, когда программа зацикливается, и влепить точку останова на этом цикле. А затем посмотреть выполнение условий цикла.